# Image Resizer User.Identity in eventhandler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

Added an AuthorizeImage eventhandler to image access restriction. Noticed the following when i was trying to check the users name and authenticationstatus:

Below will not result in exception, but seem to break it. Default icon for image not found is displayed no matter authenticated or not.
Tested this.User = same result. HttpContext.Current.User = same result

```
Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage += delegate(IHttpModule sender, HttpContext context, IUrlAuthorizationEventArgs e)
{
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { context.Response.Redirect("http://db2.stb00.s-msn.com/i/AF/263B63C5E656379CEE93E7A8692EC7.gif"); }    
};
```

The below work just fine(this.User and HttpCOntext.Current.User as well)

```
Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage += delegate(IHttpModule sender, HttpContext context, IUrlAuthorizationEventArgs e)
{
    context.Response.Redirect("http://db2.stb00.s-msn.com/i/AF/263B63C5E656379CEE93E7A8692EC7.gif"); 
};
```

This always redirects

```
Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage += delegate(IHttpModule sender, HttpContext context, IUrlAuthorizationEventArgs e)
{
    if (context.User == null)
        context.Response.Redirect("http://db2.stb00.s-msn.com/i/AF/263B63C5E656379CEE93E7A8692EC7.gif");
};
```

I started testing in Application_Start but actually tried Application_PostAuthenticateRequest as well. Though the result where the same. Im authenticating via custom code but using standard formsatuhentication to set the cookie. [Authorize] works fine in the application. Any suggestion to what could have gone wrong here?

Comment: Please, if you're getting the 'not found' icon for an image, open the URL directly and get the actual error message.

Comment: Sorry should have added that. I only get nullreference exception, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." marking the row containing "if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { context.Response.Redirect("http://db2.stb00.s-msn.com/i/AF/263B63C5E656379CEE93E7A8692EC7.gif"); } ".

So context.User isnt instantiated it seems. The question is why. Since authentication works in other aspects (and @User.Identity.Name in the view gives me the username) im suspecting something related to the eventhandler?

Comment: ASP.NET doesn't populate context.User for anonymous users. If you're not anonymous, then your code isn't loading User prior to PostAuthorize, which is a bug.

Comment: " then your code isn't loading User prior to PostAuthorize" Bit of a bummer since im using standard forms authentication. The only line of formsauth i have is actually "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, RememberMe);" at this stage.

Comment: I searched around a bit and saw a discussion regarding changed in IIS7 and integrated appools in regards to global.asax problem. Anyway it gave me the idea to switch webserver. Im sitting on VS 2012 RC so i switched from iis express to Visual Studio Dev Server and now it works fine. A bit strange.

Comment: Tried switch back and forth to be sure the problem persist but keeps working fine in VS Dev Server and not att all in IIS Express

Comment: I pinpointed the problem. In IIS Express (no matter integrated or classic mode) using .jpg.ashx?width=100 works. But .jpg?width=100 returns an empty user.identity. Could this be an imageresizer bug or perhaps iis express issue? STrange thing is that as i said before it works in VS dev server. Havent tried running it on the server yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server is configured to only run the FormsAuthenticationModule for certain request extensions, such as .aspx, .ashx, etc. There are two ways to solve this.

1. Remove and re-add the FormsAuthenticationModule in `<system.webServer>
   <modules>` (For Integrated Mode), dropping the precondition="managedHandler" attribute:
2. Enable RAMMFAR (runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests)

This post contains more details about implementing #1 and #2:

[How do I protect static files with ASP.NET form authentication on IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903292/how-do-i-protect-static-files-with-asp-net-form-auhentication-on-iis-7-5)

Comment: Solution 1 is the way to go, if possible.  See [SCOTT HANSELMAN's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx) for more info on RAMMFAR, and why to avoid it.