# Access HttpContext.User On Pipeline.PostRewrite

Tags: imageresizer

I want to have custom validation of PostRewrite to only allow the owner of the image to request bigger images but when I try to validate the User is always null.

Is there any way that I can get the current user from the Imageresizing pipeline ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11739699/166893

Answer (score 0):

Your server is configured to only run the FormsAuthenticationModule for certain request extensions, such as .aspx, .ashx, etc. There are two ways to solve this.

1. Remove and re-add the FormsAuthenticationModule in `<system.webServer>
   <modules>` (For Integrated Mode), dropping the precondition="managedHandler" attribute:
2. Enable RAMMFAR (runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests)

This post contains more details about implementing #1 and #2:

[How do I protect static files with ASP.NET form authentication on IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903292/how-do-i-protect-static-files-with-asp-net-form-auhentication-on-iis-7-5)