# Prevent Anonymous Access to Content of the folder in .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, .net-framework-version

I have this following section in my web.config file in ASP.Net 4.5 project.

I've added couple of .doc files into that folder. 
Whenever I run the project (either logged in or logged out) through VS 2012, It allows me the direct access to the files inside that folder. I need to protect the anonymous users from accessing to the files.

```
HTTP://localhost/Test/Test1.doc
```

But when the URL is `HTTP://localhost/Test` it redirects me to login page.

```
<location path="Test">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
     </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I wonder how it was working before in .Net Framework 4 on VS 2010.
It prevents the anonymous users from accessing to the content of the folder.

Did I miss any settings in my web.Config file using . Net Framework 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is that ASP.net is not servicing the .doc files.

The web requests for those files are not being handled by.net so IIS allows the access directly.

This issue was answered by Joel on a similar thread: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903292/how-do-i-protect-static-files-with-asp-net-form-auhentication-on-iis-7-5)

Many Thanks to Joel!