# How to show static content of a website only to authenticated users using Asp.net and IIS 7.0?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7

I have tried to show the static content of a website like pdf files or images only to authenticated users using ASP.net Forms authentication and authorization rules. I put in my root config file the following configuration :

```
<system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx">
      </authentication>
</system.web>
```

And in the folder that I have the pdf files and images a config file with the following configuration:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web> 
      <authorization> 
         <deny users="?" /> 
      </authorization> 
   </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

It works when I am not login in the website I cannot see the files and I get redirected to the login page, but the issue is that I cannot see the files even when I log in to the website, it still redirects me like I am not logged in when I try to see the files. Can you please help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903292/how-do-i-protect-static-files-with-asp-net-form-authentication-on-iis-7-5

Comment: This works only running the website in Integrated mode? Because I have an issue running my website in Integrated mode. I have an website that uses .Net 2.0 and I have edited the config file to use <handlers> instead of <httpHandlers> and <modules> instead of <httpModules> that are for classic app pool, but the website never loads, it takes to much time and then it just throws the error ERR_Connection_Timed_Out, when I turn back to classic app pool there is no issue. I don't know where the issue could be and what should I do?